# Cannot convert from 'void' to 'byte[]'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do this:

```
public string getName(uint offset, byte[] buffer)
{
     return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(PS3.GetMemory(offset, buffer));
}
```

But it returns me an error:

```
cannot convert from 'void' to 'byte[]'
```

But I don't know why.

```
public void GetMemory(uint offset, byte[] buffer)
{
      if (SetAPI.API == SelectAPI.TargetManager)
            Common.TmApi.GetMemory(offset, buffer);
      else if (SetAPI.API == SelectAPI.ControlConsole)
            Common.CcApi.GetMemory(offset, buffer);
}
```

Comment: You don't return anything from `GetMemory` to pass to `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`.

Comment: @esc: No, `ref` isn't required at all here. I'm not sure what you've misunderstood, but `ref` has nothing to do with the issue here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Contrary to the other answer, I don't think you need to modify your `GetMemory` method, which looks like it's *calling* `void` methods (e.g. [here](https://github.com/NzV/PS3Lib-Unofficial/blob/master/PS3API.cs)).

It looks like `GetMemory` writes *into* the buffer you provide, so you may just need:

```
// Name changed to comply with .NET naming conventions
public string GetName(uint offset, byte[] buffer)
{
    // Populate buffer
    PS3.GetMemory(offset, buffer);
    // Convert it to string - assuming the whole array is filled with useful data
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
}
```

On the other hand, that is assuming that the buffer is *exactly* the right size for the name. Is that actually the case? It's unclear where you expect the value to come from, or how long you expect it to be.

Comment: Looking at the API reference you linked in the other answer, this is literally the only correct answer. Though, based on the `CcApi` he could use `return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(PS3.GetBytes(offset, buffer));` in `GetName` as well. (`/// <summary>Like Get memory but this function return directly the buffer from the offset (ulong).</summary>`)

Answer (score 0):

Right now your function `GetMemory` does not have return type(void). Change your function  `public void GetMemory(uint offset, byte[] buffer)` to return `byte[]` instead of `void`.

```
public byte[] GetMemory(uint offset, byte[] buffer)
{
      if (SetAPI.API == SelectAPI.TargetManager)
            return Common.TmApi.GetMemory(offset, buffer);
      else if (SetAPI.API == SelectAPI.ControlConsole)
            return Common.CcApi.GetMemory(offset, buffer);
}
```

then you can use in this way:-

```
public string getName(uint offset, byte[] buffer)
{
     return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(PS3.GetMemory(offset, buffer));
}
```

Assumption:- `Common.TmApi.GetMemory` and `Common.CcApi.GetMemory` returning `byte[]`

Comment: Same comment as I made to roryap - this assumes the *other* GetMemory functions return a `byte[]`

Comment: Thanks @Tim, I made this as assumption

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetMemory` method does not have a return type (it's `void`).  Therefore, you can't use it in `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(PS3.GetMemory(offset, buffer))` because `GetString` expects a value to be returned from `GetMemory`.  Change your `GetMemory` method so it has a return type of `byte[]`:

```
public byte[] GetMemory(uint offset, byte[] buffer)
{
      if (SetAPI.API == SelectAPI.TargetManager)
            return Common.TmApi.GetMemory(offset, buffer);
      else if (SetAPI.API == SelectAPI.ControlConsole)
             return Common.CcApi.GetMemory(offset, buffer);
}
```

As was pointed out in the comments, I'm making the assumption here that `Common.TmApi.GetMemory` and `Common.CcApi.GetMemory` also have a return type of `byte[]`.

**EDIT:**  As Jon Skeet has pointed out, it seems that `Common.TmApi.GetMemory` and `Common.CcApi.GetMemory` *do not* return any values, so you may want to consider his answer or a similar approach that passes the "return" value in as an output parameter to your `GetMemory` method and then passes the value on a subsequent line to `GetString`.

Comment: of course, that would only work if those *other* `GetMemory` functions return a `byte[]` too, which the OP probably needs to clarify.

Comment: As Jon Skeet said in the other answer, this will not compile. https://github.com/NzV/PS3Lib-Unofficial/blob/master/API/CCAPI/CCAPI.cs

Answer (score 0):

As you show in your code, the function `GetMemory` returns a void (in other words, doesn't return anything). So you can't pass the return value of that function into another function (in this case the `GetString` function).

You'll need to find a way to modify `GetMemory` to return a `byte[]` array instead, or alternatively find some other way to access that memory that you need.

Answer (score -2):

GetMemory method should return byte[]:

```
public byte[] GetMemory(uint offset, byte[] buffer)
{
  if (SetAPI.API == SelectAPI.TargetManager)
    return Common.TmApi.GetMemory(offset, buffer);
  else if (SetAPI.API == SelectAPI.ControlConsole)
    return Common.CcApi.GetMemory(offset, buffer);
  else
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: That's not going to compile, given the implementations of `TmApi` and `CcApi` I've seen, e.g. https://github.com/NzV/PS3Lib-Unofficial/blob/master/API/CCAPI/CCAPI.cs